# Where should I design main-layout, When I create navigation drawer activity as launcher activity?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I want to have a `navigation drawer` in `main activity` so I created a `navigation drawer Activity` as a launcher Activity.

I designed my `main-layout` in `content_layout` , I don't know its correct or not, but when I want to put an `exit-button`(ImageButton) in the bottom it doesn't work and it doesn't go the bottom of page it goes left.
this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton
                android:background="@drawable/guidance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageButton>
            <ImageButton
                android:onClick="btn_about"
                android:background="@drawable/about"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageButton
            android:background="@drawable/exit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `RelativeLayout` instead of linear layout for the 2nd linear layout. Inside your exit `ImageButton` use         `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. This will move your ImageButton to the bottom-left